# Is fs.watch() broken in Node v13 or am I doing something wrong?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, fs, winston

I've been stuck trying to set up a file watcher that detects when new data is added to a file. The general sequence is 1.) a client connects to server. 2.) server logs to a file. 3.) `fs.watch()` detects the file has changed and runs a function, in this case a simple `console.log('New log entry')`

Everything seems to work except `fs.watch()` does not detect when new messages are added to the log file. However if I click on the log file in VScode it seems to trigger it. Is this a bug in newer versions of Node or am I doing something wrong here?

I realize I could use `fs.watchFile()` but I was hoping to avoid the overhead of polling...

```
// src/index.js
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const server = require('http').createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);
const logger = require('./logger');
const fs = require('fs');

fs.watch('./logs/combined.log', (event) => {
  if (event === 'change') {
    console.log('New log entry');
  }
});

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../public')));
app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../public', 'index.html'));
});

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  logger.info('a user connected');
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8888;

server.listen(PORT, () => {
  logger.info(`Listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

-

```
// src/logger.js
const winston = require('winston');

const logger = winston.createLogger({
  level: 'info',
  format: winston.format.json(),
  transports: [
    new winston.transports.File({ filename: 'logs/combined.log' })
  ]
});

module.exports = logger
```

-

```
// public/index.html
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8888');
</script>
```

-

```
// simplified test
const logger = require('./logger');
const fs = require('fs');

fs.watch('./logs/combined.log', event => {
  if (event === 'change') {
    console.log('log file has updated');
  }
});

function intervalFunc() {
  logger.info('new log message');
}
setInterval(intervalFunc, 5000);
```

Comment: If you want something easy and consistent, you should check out [chokidar](https://github.com/paulmillr/chokidar) it is used by Microsoft's Visual Studio Code, gulp, karma, PM2, browserify, webpack, BrowserSync...etc...

Comment: Thanks @MattOestreich , I started with chokidar and had the same issues. I then reduced the code to just try the fs.watch() to see if I could get it to work. No luck, and now im here :).

Comment: I suppose we should take a step back... so you want to log to a file when a connection is established, then you want to run some code when an entry is added to the log... why don't you just move the code you want to run 'on file change' into the `io.on('connection', ..)` handler?

Comment: @MattOestreich Well this is just a very simple example. In reality this is part of a much bigger application that has many different things sending to the log file. There is then an admin front end that I would like to have the logs streamed to in real time. This was just the cleanest approach I could think of.  So I wasnt sure if my code was bad or there was an issue with newer implementations of fs.watch().

Comment: So instead of logging `a user connected` I would be emitting the newest log entry to the admin frontend every time some part of the app added to the logs.

Comment: Would it be possible to monitor the file from a separate node process?

Comment: [I just tested this](https://github.com/oze4/chokidar-child-process) and it appears you could even start the child process from within your main app... I wonder if the socket is messing with things? I tested this on a Mac btw.

Comment: Nice I'll check it out. I also added a simplified test to the original post that you could maybe try and see if you have an issue with it? I still think something is weird with fs.watch() but i may be crazy

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208461/discussion-between-hexxnine-and-matt-oestreich).

Comment: Hey sorry about that I had to go to sleep last night so I could get up for work.. Did you ever get this resolved? If not, can you supply the `package.json` file you used in that minimal example? I'd like to test it out.

Comment: Hey thanks for all your help I appreciate it. I'm beginning to think it has something to do with the way Winston is accessing? writing to the file? Here is a link to the [Simple test](https://github.com/MA-MacDonald/fs-node-test). When I try to use Winston with your example it causes the same issue.

Comment: Nice work! May want to open an issue on Winstons GitHub.. Def sounds like an issue with Winston if the issue only starts happening after you add Winston to the demo I created (proves Winston is what breaks it).. Feel free to reference the demo I made and tell them the demo breaks after Winston is added (Winston writing to log not triggering file watcher).. Good luck! Cheers. I should mention I did search their open and closed issues but could not find one for this issue, so I don't think anyone has already filed an issue for it.

Comment: Sounds good, I will open an issue with Winston. Thanks again for your example it really helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Update:***

So it [looks like Winston comes with built-in listeners](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston#awaiting-logs-to-be-written-in-winston).  These listeners act similar to a file watcher, and allow you to hook into certain events.  One of the events you can hook into is called 'data' - this lets you listen for when data is written to file, and run a callback function.

This provides similar behavior to `file.watch`.

They allow you to listen for the following events:

- close
- data
- end
- error
- readable

I tested this on Windows and it works perfectly.

This is the test file I am using:

```js
const winston = require('winston');

const { createLogger, format: { json }, transports: { File } } = winston;

const logger = createLogger({
  level: 'info',
  format: json(),
  transports: [
    new File({ filename: './log.txt' })
  ],  
});

/**
 * Added a built in Winston listener
 */
logger.addListener('data', chunk => {
    console.log('\r\n[winston listener] we have logged some data:\n', chunk)
})

/**
 * Their documentation seems to use the `.on` method.
 * 
 * This appears to provide the same type of behavior that `.addListener` does.
 * 
 * I'm not sure which is best, or recommended, `.addListener` or `.on` - you
 * may want to dig deeper into that.
 */
logger.on('data', chunk => {
    console.log('\r\n[winston on "data"] we have logged some data:\n', chunk);
});

setInterval(() => {
  logger.info('new log message');
}, 5000);
```

---

so I've been giving this some thought and at first I believed this was happening because Winston uses write streams to update files..

Then I went ahead and tried to replicate your issue, but I cannot reproduce it.

Each time the log file gets updated, a message is written to console (meaning, `fs.watch` is working.

Are you using Windows? What version of Node are you on?

This is the test file I am using:

```js
const winston = require('winston');
const fs = require('fs');

const { createLogger, format: { json }, transports: { File } } = winston;

const logger = createLogger({
  level: 'info',
  format: json(),
  transports: [
    new File({ filename: './log.txt' })
  ]
});

fs.watch('./log.txt', event => { 
  if (event === 'change') {
    console.log('log file has updated');
  }
});

setInterval(() => {
  logger.info('new log message');
}, 5000);
```

Comment: I am on windows 10 using Node v13.9.0 on my work pc and Node v13.7.0 on my personal pc, same issue on both. I can record a quick screen grab to demonstrate later today. The only time it will print to the console it when I open the log file (im guessing because accessing the file changes meta data or something that triggers a change event?) I will link to a video example when I get home later today.

Comment: I was able to test this on Windows (it was working for me on a Mac) and I am experiencing the same issue now.  I did notice when I physically click on the file, it will write to console.. I personally believe this has something to do with how Winston uses streams to write to the files.

Comment: @HexxNine so I believe I have figured something out, that gives you the same behavior you are looking for with `file.watch`.  I have updated my answer with this info - please check it out and let me know what you think.

Comment: Nice work Matt! Its working nicely. There is definitely some inconsistencies between platforms it appears. Thanks for working that out, much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The node documentation for [fs.watch](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fs_fs_watch_filename_options_listener) has an entire [Caveats](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fs_caveats) section that states at the very beginning:

> The fs.watch API is not 100% consistent across platforms, and is
>   unavailable in some situations.

You should read that section for more info, but you may end up having to use [fs.watchfile](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fs_fs_watchfile_filename_options_listener) if you cannot get `fs.watch` to work reliably for you.

[UPDATE]

The Caveats section's [Filename Argument](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fs_filename_argument) subsection also states this:

> Even on supported platforms, `filename` is not always guaranteed to be
>   provided. Therefore, don't assume that `filename` argument is always
>   provided in the callback, and have some fallback logic if it is `null`.

Since you do not need to use the `filename` argument (and you already know the filename anyway), your callback should not be testing for a truthy `filename` argument.

Comment: Thanks, I have read the docs, and "is unavailable in some situations" is quite vague. I am on a Windows machine. What am looking for is if there is an issue with the code, or does this fall into the "some situations" portion of unavailability.

Comment: See my updated answer, in case that helps. Yes, the documentation is a bit vague, but supporting this feature across a wide variety of filesystems is really hard, and also really hard to document completely.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I'm not sure why that check was there, but after removing it, it did not help. Logs are being written to the log file but file changes are still not detected.

Comment: If I open the log file is VScode and type directly in it, changes are detected however when Winston writes to the file it is not detected until I open the file...not sure if that helps narrow anything down.